# Migrating stripe subscription to be SCA compliant

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription, I collect card details on signup with a 7 day trial, after which the subscription bills monthly.

From what I understand the subscription API is not SCA compliant. Instead

1. An `off_session` payment Intent must [first be setup](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/saving-cards#saving-card-without-payment) when collecting card details.
2. At the end of each month a scheduler must be triggered to attempt to charge [the registered card](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/charging-saved-cards#off-session-payments-with-saved-cards).

Is this the case? Am I now responsible for scheduling payments?

---

### Update

For those who want some starter code, [I created a working playground here with subscriptions, frontend (react) and backend (express) on glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stripe-sca-subscription-react?path=README.md:22:0).

[image: edAUunAs5S]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true that Stripe's Subscription API is not SCA-ready, it is, and you don't have to set up your own scheduling like that. The docs you linked to are generally aimed at processing one-off payments(like saving a customer's details and then allowing them to use them again when they re-visit your site to purchase something new, for example) as opposed to recurring ones.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment describes how to set up a subscription in a way that is SCA-ready. While the customer is on-session on your payment page, you collect card details and create a subscription for the customer, which will generally attempt a payment for the first billing period. You then check the status of the subscription after it's created, and handle the outcomes:

- the subscription is `active` and the payment was successful, so you can proceed with provisioning your service to the customer.
- the subscription is [`incomplete`](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#incomplete) — for SCA purposes, let's say this is because 3D Secure authentication was required for that first payment. In this case, the `latest_invoice` of the subscription exposes a [PaymentIntent property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-payment_intent), and you use that PaymentIntent in conjunction with your frontend code using stripe.js to walk the customer through [authenticating the payment](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#handling-action-required), and that activates the subscription.
- the subscription is `trialing` — if the subscription [doesn't involve an initial payment](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#non-payment), like when using a trial period for example, you can also check if the subscription has a `pending_setup_intent`. You can use this on your frontend to have the customer complete a 3D Secure authentication, so that future payments(like the first one after the trial) are more likely to successfully claim an exemption and not require having the user authenticate at that point.

You can also instead use Stripe Checkout to easily collect payment details and set up a customer and subscription for you, while also handling any initial authentication that's needed : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#create-subscriptions

As for the recurring payments, Billing can handle that for you. You can configure you settings to [automatically email the customer to complete 3D Secure](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#3ds-payment-settings) if it's encountered on a recurring payment. So you can absolutely build an SCA-ready solution with the subscriptions API on Stripe.

Comment: In the trialing scenario, I have got the `subscription.pending_setup_intent`. However when I attempt the `stripe.handleCardSetup` I get the error “The payment method supplied … does not belong to a Customer. Please attach the payment method to this Customer before using it with a SetupIntent”. Why would that be? I attach the token with `stripe.customers.update`

Comment: I made a new question for this followup question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57200228/1376627

Comment: The page you linked says to use the method `createToken()` to create a token to be used when creating the customer. In the [migration guide to use SCA](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration#elements) it says to instead use `createPaymentMethod()`. I followed the subscription guide with payment method and received the error `This customer has no attached payment source`. We save cards with customers with `paymentMethod` (not `token`). Do you know if payment method is allowed for subscriptions, just like with one-time payments? (otherwise we won't be able to reuse the cards)

Comment: @karllekko Thanks for that it was very helpful.  I have it sorted now.  I had been lost in the Stripe documentation for days.  I used: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/set-up-subscription#web-collect-card-details
Then implemented SCA afterwards using the link you put above:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment