# Please attach the payment method to this Customer before using it with a SetupIntent | Migrating stripe subscription to be SCA compliant

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a subscription, I collect card details on signup with a 7 day trial, after which the subscription bills monthly.

I have followed the documentation to [create a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment).

Testing the flow with a fake card [`4000002500003155`](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/saving-cards#testing) which requires setup, I encountered an issue.

My setup is as follows.

1. Frontend does `stripe.createToken()`
2. Server does `stripe.customers.update(customer_id, { source })` with token
3. Server creates the subscription

   ```
     stripe.subscriptions.create({
       customer: self.stripe_customer_id,
       tax_percent: 20,
       expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent', 'pending_setup_intent'],
       ...plan
     }
   ```
4. As expected the subscription response `subscription.pending_setup_intent` is not null and has `{ client_secret: 'seti__', status: 'requires_action', payment_method: 'card___', ... }`.
5. On the frontend I attempt to handle the pending setup intent on the frontend with `stripe.handleCardSetup(client_secret, {});` but I got the following error.

> The payment method supplied (pm____) does not belong to a Customer, but you supplied Customer cus____. Please attach the payment method to this Customer before using it with a SetupIntent.

I tried to remedy this by attaching the paymentMethod to the user before step 5

```
stripe.paymentMethods.attach('card____', {
  customer: customer_id
});
```

But I got the following error

> The payment method you provided has already been attached to a customer.

---

#### Update

I replaced steps 1 and 2 by [attaching payment method from setupIntent to the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/saving-cards#saving-card-without-payment) using `handleCardSetup` and `paymentMethods.attach`. I was able to succesfully create subscription after that point. `subscription.pending_setup_intent` is then returned as `null` which means it is successful.

For those who want some starter code, [I created a working playground here with subscriptions, frontend (react) and backend (express) on glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stripe-sca-subscription-react?path=README.md:22:0).

[image: edAUunAs5S]

Comment: I tried recreating your flow and didn't get an error with the SetupIntent. I'd suggest writing an email to Stripe's support with the full details you gave here, and including the IDs of the customer `cus_xxx` and so on, so they can investigate in more detail

Comment: When you call `handleCardSetup`, are you maybe actually passing in a Card Element too? Because then it would be reading a new card from the input there and trying to use that unattached card with the SetupIntent, hence the error. But in your question you say `stripe.handleCardSetup(client_secret, {});` which seems correct.

Comment: Yes passing the card element. I believe the issue was that `createToken` is for non SCA - instead I started by setting up the intent on the customer.

Comment: Where does `stripe.updatePaymentDetails({source})` come from? It is part of the Stripe API client libraries? Or is that your own function?

Comment: updated @Flux was indeed my wrapper function

Comment: For handling the initial payment outcome for Subscriptions, use `stripe.handleCardPayment` (and not `stripe.handleCardSetup`). See documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#requires-action-2

Comment: There is no initial payment so doesn't apply @Flux

Comment: I saw you replaced steps 1 and 2 by attaching payment method from setupIntent to the customer. Has it worked for you ? When I do that, the `pending_setup_intent` parameter is null for me. How did you manage to get a non-null value ?

Comment: That means it was successful if it is `null` as you completed steps 1 and 2, so it's all good?

Comment: Your glitch link is down. Is that still available? @david_adler